# Making a game menu in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how to make a menu for my game. All I want is for when the game first starts up, there is a play button, which when clicked starts the game.

Right now I have MainMenu class:

```
package Classes 
{
import flash.display.Sprite;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import Main;

/**
 * Main Menu
 * @author Craig Jackson
 */

public class MainMenu extends Sprite
{

    public function MainMenu() 
    {
        var playButton:Sprite = new Sprite();
        playButton.graphics.beginFill(0x666666);
        playButton.graphics.drawRect(300, 300, 100, 100);
        playButton.graphics.endFill();

        addChild(playButton);

        playButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, clickedPlayButton);
    }

    public function  clickedPlayButton():void 
    {
        // Not sure what to do here
    }

}
```

}

In my Main class, I create an instance of the MainMenu class and add it to the stage. This works fine. My problem comes with referencing the Main class in my MainMenu class. Because I have function: playGame in my Main class with all the code needed to start the game. I can't work out how to call that function from my MainMenu class or make it trigger it in my Main class.

I think I will need to dispatch an event, but I can't seem to understand how event dispatching works.

Does anyone know how dispatching an event would work in my case, or any other ideas?

Comment: Normally, you would take care of all this in your Main class. For my game, I made a button instance that, when clicked, triggers a separate event that hides the button and loads the first level.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create simple custom events by just making a `new Event()`:

```
public function clickedPlayButton(e:MouseEvent):void 
{
    dispatchEvent(new Event("PLAY_CLICKED"));
}
```

Then in `Main.as` you can listen for that event like so:

```
menu.addEventListener("PLAY_CLICKED", playClicked);
```

Comment: I'm getting the error: Fault] exception, information=ArgumentError: Error #1063: Argument count mismatch on Classes::MainMenu/clickedPlayButton(). Expected 0, got 1.

Comment: Oh, callbacks for event listeners need to accept an event parameter. I've edited my answer to add `e:MouseEvent`.

Answer (score 0):

Do something like this in your playClicked function.

```
removeChild(playButton);
gameScreen = new GameScreen(); //Assuming you have a movieclip called GameScreen which holds your gamescreen
addChild(gameScreen);
```

Add all your game graphics and interface to the GameScreen movieclip.